# Remove rows of 2 columns and shifting up from the next row

Tags: python, pandas

How do I remove each row for column a and b and replace a and b from the next row? I am not sure how to do this in an efficient way because I have a big dataset.

My dataframe

```
╔═══════════════════════════╗
║ Name      a   b   c   d   ║
╠═══════════════════════════╣
║ Lisa      5   4   1   3   ║
║ Timmy     3   2   7   2   ║  
║ Rann      2   3   1   5   ║
║ Bob       1   6   3   4   ║
╚═══════════════════════════╝
```

I want to change it into this

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Name      c   d   a   b                  ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Lisa      1   3   3   2                  ║
║ Timmy     7   2   2   3                  ║  
║ Rann      1   5   1   6                  ║
║ Bob       3   4  (a & b from next row)   ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

a and b for Lisa is replaced with Timmy's a and b, Timmy is replaced by Rann and so on. How should I do this without hard-coding it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [pandas.DataFrame.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) function to achieve that

```
df[['a','b']] = df[['a','b']].shift(-1)
```

Out:

```
    Name    a   b   c   d
0   Lisa    3.0 2.0 1   3
1   Timmy   2.0 3.0 7   2
2   Rann    1.0 6.0 1   5
3   Bob     NaN NaN 3   4
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do this using index instead of the column names? Because I have 22 columns to shift.

Comment: Its possible with index as well, any criteria to select the columns to shift

Comment: You can select the columns with columns indexer,-> apply shift `df[df.columns[1:3]].shift(-1) `

Comment: Thanks. One last question, How do I shift a and b to the end of the dataframe?

Comment: `df.shift(1) ` would shift down the values, as `df.shift(-1)` upwards :)

Comment: if you dont know the no of values to shift, Calculate the null values and shift according to that `df.shift(df[df.columns[0]].isnull().sum()])`